# How to Clean a complex NSMutableArrray safely?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a mutableArray (array),  element is a dictionary (item), each item has two keys, one points to a dictionary, and the other points to a mutableArray(subArray).

The question is: after array used, I should clean it.
should I just do like this: [array removeAllObjects];
or I need to iterate array to call: [subArray removeAllObjects];

another words，are codes bellow in the red box necessary?

[image]

Comment: Obsolete, and the `if` part as well. All you need is the single line `[cartItems removeAllObjects];`

Comment: haha, can't agree more now~

Answer (score 1):

```
+ (void)clearShoppingCart {
    [carItems removeAllObjects];
}
```

Do like Gerd says.The app wouldn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *dic in cartItems) {
    [dic[@"products"] removeAllObjects];
}
[cartItems removeAllObjects];
```

and

```
[cartItems removeAllObjects];
```

After both code: Result will

> cartItems is empty dictionary

Comment: There's no reason for the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to release the cartItems object, which will eventually clean everything.

```
self.cartItems = nil
```

Comment: There's a big difference between clearing the cart and removing the entire cart.

Comment: I see. but in my case , don,t need set catItems nil, beacause maybe I'll use it again soon.

Comment: Instead of setting it to nil, you can just create a new one here

Answer (score 0):

If `dic[@"products"]` isn't owned by another instance, then `[cartItems removeAllObjects]` is enough to remove everything.

But, if `dic[@"products"]` is owned by another instance. For example,

```
B.array = dic[@"products"];

[cartItems removeAllObjects];
NSLog(@"%@", B.array); ///< B.array won't be empty
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: maybe I am a bit distracted.
the code in the red box is not necessary. removeAllObject or even self.cartItems = @[] are also okay.

I doubt if this kind of clean-up is necessary.

I would say it depends on the reference counting of the object being contained. like, @[A, B, C], are there any pointer pointing A, B or C?

> First, I would like to remind that ARC in objective-c work based on
>   the reference count of the object. if the count become 0, it will be
>   dealloc soon.

Let break it into cases,
let container = Array or Dictionary.

1. only the container strong-holding the objects: for @[A, B, C] / @{@"a" : A}. If there is no more strong pointer pointing to the container, the array will be soon dealloc. The strong pointing by the container to the objects will be canceled. As no more strong pointing to A, B, C. Their counts become zero, and they will be dealloc too.

In your cases, if the array(say, X) that self.cartItems pointing is only pointed by self.cartItems. when you self.cartItems = nil, as no more pointer is pointing X, X will dealloc, and case 1 will occurs if it fulfil "only the container strong-holding the objects"

2. if not only the container strong-holding the objects: it will process like case1, but let say ,if A and C if pointing by another pointers, when the container dealloc, B will be dealloc, but A and C wont as are still be strong-pointed.

In your case,

```
self.cartItems = @[A, B, C];
self.specialCartItem = A;
self.discountCartItem = C;

self.cartItems = nil
```

A and C will still be here. at least you set self.specialCartItem and self.discountCartItem to nil;

So, you can foresee that if it is a nested container. it just works in a recursive basis.

The key point is there is no other side strong pointer pointing to the container and the objects. I would conclude that you just need to every pointer you use. And it should be okay.

CORRECT ME if I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it.